# SonarQube rule to verify db access method

Tags: sonarqube

Is there a way to verify by SonarQube the method that is used to access to a database?

For example: I would that all db access are doing with MyBatis framework and not in other way.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the "Architectural Constraint" rule template that allows you (for instance) to check that (some of) your classes do not access some other classes.

See the [Architecture Rule Engine documentation page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Architecture+Rule+Engine) for more information on how to achieve that.

Comment: Ok, I nave seen it but with architecture constrain I can only forbid access to a class in a package from another class.But how i can verify that all access to a DB are made with MyBatis framework? Can You make me dome example? Thank You!